# Finding the total or average from four input fields and displaying the value in another input field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use JS to get the sum or the average of four numbers from an input field and then displaying that in another text field. There's a radio button to choose if it's the total or average that is to be displayed.

Here is my html for the form:

```
<form name="calculate">

Mark: <input type="number" name="number" id="num1"><br>
Mark: <input type="number" name="number" id="num2"><br>
Mark: <input type="number" name="number" id="num3"><br>
Mark: <input type="number" name="number" id="num4"><br>

<input type="radio" id="numTotal" name="choice" value="total">Find total</input>
<input type="radio" id="numAvg" name="choice" value="average">Find average</input>
<br>

<input type="submit" form="calculate" value="Submit" onclick="calculate();">
<input type="reset" form="calculate" value="Reset">
<br>
Result: <input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="" disabled>

</form>
```

And down here is my JS code:

```
function calculate(){

var arr = document.getElementsByName("number");
var tot = 0;
var av = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value)){
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
}

av = tot/arr.length;

if(document.getElementById("numTotal").checked) {
    document.calculate.getElementbyId("result").value = tot;
}

if(document.getElementById("numAvg").checked) {
    document.getElementbyId("result").value = av;
}

}
```

After running this, the result input field doesn't show the input. Is the error in my script or in the html or both?

Comment: The document.calculate.getElementbyId("result").value = tot; is already removed in the one I'm currently testing as it doesn't work.

Comment: changed the by to **By** `document.getElementsById("result").value = tot;` and I changed form name to calc and function name to calculateFunc, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateFunc() {

        var arr = document.getElementsByName("number");
        var tot = 0;
        var av = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (parseInt(arr[i].value)) {
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
            }
        }

        av = tot / arr.length;

        if (document.getElementById("numTotal").checked) {
            document.getElementById("result").value = tot;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("numAvg").checked) {
            document.getElementById("result").value = av;
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>

<div class="form">
<form name="calculate">

Mark: <input type="number" name="number" id="num1"><br>
Mark: <input type="number" name="number" id="num2"><br>
Mark: <input type="number" name="number" id="num3"><br>
Mark: <input type="number" name="number" id="num4"><br>

<input type="radio" id="numTotal" name="choice" value="total">Find total</input>
<input type="radio" id="numAvg" name="choice" value="average">Find average</input>
<br>
<br>
Result: <input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="" disabled>

</form>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="calculateFunc();">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</div>
```

This is work for me in Chrome :)

Comment: This works for me too! Perhaps it's because of the div and return false and my results and buttons order. I've still much to learn I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.calculate.getElementbyId("result").value = tot;

if(document.getElementById("numTotal").checked) {
    document.calculate.getElementbyId("result").value = tot;
}

if(document.getElementById("numAvg").checked) {
    document.getElementbyId("result").value = av;
}
```

need to replace

```
 document.getElementbyId("result").value = tot;

 if(document.getElementById("numTotal").checked) {
     document.calculate.getElementById("result").value = tot;
 }

 if(document.getElementById("numAvg").checked) {
     document.getElementById("result").value = av;
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry about that, forgot to remove that but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: getElementbyId > getElementById with 'ById'

Comment: The result still won't be in the result input field. Any other ideas?

Comment: rename the form name and the function name :) it has the same name!! for functoin use 'calculateFunc' instead of 'calculate'

Comment: Still doesn't do anything with the results. I really hope it's not one of those facepalm mistakes haha.